# Match string format with regex

Tags: php, regex, bash, shell

I know there are tons of questions about regex string format, but I am very new to this and I haven't been able to do it myself. How can I use regex to match a string with the following format?

`xx_x_a.zip`

where x is a number and a is a letter. Example:

`33_2_f.zip`

It must not match:

`33_2_f_abc.zip`

The format must always be like `2digits`+`_`+`1digit`+`_`+`1letter`+`.zip`

Comment: _“and I haven't been able to do it myself”_ - that means, you tried something at least? Shows us what you tried then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
/^[0-9]{2}_[0-9]_[a-z]\.zip$/
```

Comment: It must be just 1 letter, so don't put + after [a-z]

Comment: Do we know that the letter must be lower-case?

Comment: How about `\d` and `\w`?

Comment: \w is no-go, because it matches not just letters. \d might match not just digits in ASCII, we don't have enough specifics about the environment